# Output results to the user

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a telegram bot. There is a piece of working code that responds to messages from the user, searches for key word matching database and sends the result to user. The problem is that the sample result gets into the console, how to send it to the user? Please, help

```
             bot.on('message', (ctx) => {
                const text = ctx.text
                const log = sequelize.query("SELECT book FROM books t WHERE (t.*)::text LIKE '%"+ text +"%'") .then( (result) => {
                    console.log(result,log)
                }) .catch( (err)  => {
                    console.log(err);
                    for (const result of results) {
                        ctx.reply(result.book);
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: You put the `reply` command in the error handler function?

Comment: I deleted it, the result is the same. Output to the console

Comment: You're not supposed to delete, you're supposed to move it to the success function (where you're currently logging it but not doing anything else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `sendMessage` api and data in `message` Your code should look like this:

```
const { QueryTypes } = sequelize;

bot.on('message', async (message) => {
  const {text, chat} = message; // https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message
  const {id: chatId} = chat; // https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat
  
  let response = '';

  try {
    const rows = await sequelize.query(
      'SELECT book FROM books t WHERE (t.*)::text LIKE :searchText', 
      {
        replacements: { searchText: `%${text}%` },
        type: QueryTypes.SELECT,
      }
    );
    
    console.log('ROWS:', rows);

    if (rows.length) {
      response = rows.map(row => row.book).join("\n");
    }
    else {
      response = 'Book not found';
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    response = 'Unable to lookup';
  }
  finally {
    if (response) {
      bot.sendMessage(chatId, response);
    }
  }
})
```

Check manuals:

1. [sendMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage)
2. [Message object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)
3. [Chat object](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat)
4. [Sequelize replacements](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/raw-queries.html#replacements)

Comment: I execute your code and have error `Unhandled rejection Error: ETELEGRAM: 400 Bad Request: message must be non-empty
`

Comment: Thank you for answer!

Comment: @anonym I've updated my answer, it makes sure book found in db to avoid empty string as response

Comment: Thank you, but it still 400 Bad Request. I will try to rewrite it based on your examples.

Comment: @anonym try updated code

Comment: It works!! thank you very much!!!

Comment: how to show the result of three records from the database. because it happens that the result of the query is large and it is difficult to analyze?

Comment: @anonym  add ` LIMIT 3 ` to end of Your query

Comment: Only three records are displayed, and the rest are not displayed `const [rows] = await sequelize.query(`SELECT book FROM books t WHERE (t.*)::text LIKE '%${text}%' LIMIT 3`);`

Comment: @anonym seems like You cannot explain in English Your needs clearly. You wanted 3 records and answered.

Comment: @anonym ok. If You want chunk it by 3 so query without LIMIT 3 and chunk rows array by 3. Google it: js chunk array by size

Comment: Yes, three records, but if the result is ten, then all ten are not displayed, but only three. How to show the result of three records in parts, like packages? and so send messages in three entries in parts

Comment: @anonym Your comment is out of scope of question. Please create another question with my code and write in question how to chunk messages by 3 or whatever

Comment: my new question: [How to divide the result into several messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69538478/how-to-divide-the-result-into-several-messages)

Comment: @anonym answered

Comment: Hello, you helped me write this telegram bot, for which I am very grateful. I would like to ask you to help me solve such a problem, if you certainly have the time and desire to help me.